# i convert my compiler to 64 bit from 32 but still i cant use more than 2GB :( why?

Tags: c++, 64-bit

i can create this array:

```
int Array[490000000];


cout << "Array Byte= " << sizeof(Array) << endl;
```

Array byte = 1,960,000,000 byte and convert gb = 1,96 GB about 2 gb whatever.

but i cant create same time these:

```
int Array[490000000];
int Array2[490000000];
```

it give error why ? sorry for bad englisgh :)

Also i checked my compiler like this:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(char *));
```

it gives me 8.

Comment: the stack isn't where you want to allocate 2GB

Comment: When you have a 2GB automatic storage variable, chances are you need to rethink the approach.

Comment: You could try allocating your array from the heap `int* Array = new int[490000000];`, it's more likely to work than the stack but there are no guarantees.

Comment: i dont need just i want to use more than 2gb but why i cant do ? :(

Comment: It depends on the OS what is possible here.  But pretty safe to assume that it does not allow you can't create a .bss section that is larger than 2GB on x64, Windows has this restriction for example.

Comment: Stack has a limited size. I'm kinda surprised it allowed to allocate 2GB there. Use heap for your purposes.

Comment: On Ubuntu, the Posix command to get _default_ stack size per thread ( ::pthread_attr_getstacksize(&tattr,    &stackSize); ) reports 8 MBytes, and 490 Million * 4 bytes per int is 1.96  G Bytes.

Comment: Try newing the array rather than putting it on the stack

Comment: On ubuntu, a C++ std::vector occupies 24 bytes in automatic memory, regardless of the number of elements.  The vector's elements are stored contiguously, just like an array, but in dynamic memory.  If you have sufficient dynamic memory, big objects (like 490 million contiguous elements ) should be in dynamic memory, and std::vector handles the dynamic memory activity for you.

Comment: int* Array = new int[490000000]; is working but it is dynamic memory :( . Also vectors will work i think. We cant use static memory much more than 2gb right ?

Comment: @EmreKaya see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595982/i-convert-my-compiler-to-64-bit-from-32-but-still-i-cant-use-more-than-2gb-wh#comment90158241_51595982)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But still I can't use more than 2 GB :( why?

The C++ language does not have semantics to modify (nor report) how much automatic memory is available (or at least I have not seen it.)  The compilers rely on the OS to provide some 'useful' amount.  You will have to search (google? your hw documents, user's manuals, etc) for how much. This limit is 'machine' dependent, in that some machines do not have as much memory as you may want.

On Ubuntu, for the last few releases, the Posix function ::pthread_attr_getstacksize(...) reports 8 M Bytes per thread.  (I am not sure of the proper terminology, but) what linux calls 'Stack' is the resource that the C++ compiler uses for the automatic memory.  For this release of OS and compiler, the limit for automatic var's is thus 8M (much smaller than 2G).

I suppose that because the next machine might have more memory, the compiler might be given a bigger automatic memory, and I've seen no semantics that will limit the size of your array based on memory size of the machine performing the compile ... 
there can can be no compile-time-report that the stack will overflow.

I see Posix has a function suggesting a way to adjust size of stack.  I've not tried it.

I have also found Ubuntu commands that can report and adjust size of various memory issues.

From https://www.nics.tennessee.edu/:

> The command to modify limits varies by shell. The C shell (csh) and
>   its derivatives (such as tcsh) use the limit command to modify limits.
>   The Bourne shell (sh) and its derivatives (such as ksh and bash) use
>   the ulimit command. The syntax for these commands varies slightly and
>   is shown below. More detailed information can be found in the man page
>   for the shell you are using.

One minor experiment ... the command prompt

& dtb_chimes

launches this work-in-progress app which uses Posix and reports 8 MByte stack (automatic var)

With the ulimit prefix command

$ ulimit -S -s 131072 ; dtb_chimes

the app now reports   134,217,728

```
 ./dtb_chimes_ut

  default Stack size:  134,217,728
                argc:            1
  1   ./dtb_chimes_ut
```

But I have not confirmed the actual allocation ...  and this is still a lot smaller than 1.96 GBytes ... but, maybe you can get there.

Note: I strongly recommend std::vector versus big array.

---

On my Ubuntu desktop, there is 4 GByte total dram (I have memory test utilities), and my dynamic memory is limited to about 3.5 GB.  Again, the amount of dynamic memory is machine dependent.

64 bits address a lot more memory than I can afford.

Answer (score 1):

C++ programs are not usually compiled to have 2Gb+ of stack space, regardless of whether it is compiled in 32-bit mode or 64-bit mode. Stack space can be increased as part of the compiler options, but even in the scenario where it is permissible to set the stack size that high, it's still not an ideomatic solution or recommended.

If you need an array of 2Gb, you should use `std::vector<int> Array(490'000'000);` (strongly recommended) or a manually created array, i.e. `int* Array = new int[490'000'000];` (remember that manually allocated memory must be manually deallocated with `delete[]`), either of which will allocate dynamic memory. You'll still want to be compiling in 64-bit mode, since this will brush up against the maximum memory limit of your application if you don't, but in your scenario, it's not strictly necessary, since 2Gb is less than the maximum memory of a 32-bit application.